# Control of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have built, with a GUI builder, a set of JLabels and 4 arrows in a JFrame. I want, when I press one of the arrows to be able to perform operations on the correspondent label. I.e when the control is on the first label the "right" arrow would "bring" the control on the right label. I also want to mention that due to GUI builder I can't(??) use array and increase/decrease the pointers. Any ideas?:)

Comment: Which GUI builder is it?

Comment: The one which is intergrated in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to pair your GUI too closely to your data. When someone clicks on a button, it should perform some action on your data. Once that action is complete, the GUI should be updated to reflect the new data. This is much easier than moving controls within the window. This is known as the [Model View Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller).

Comment: Not exactly.Lets think that I have the neccessary time(and knowledge) to make my frame from the beginning without the builder.What would I do?Create a JLabel array and when I press "right" then an event will take place doing i++(where i is the array pointer for rows).I know that I am violating MVC but I dont care much, because the deadline is near:-P

Comment: So it would not be a huge step to have an array of strings. The event still increments i, but then additionally refreshes what is displayed in the Jlabel.

Comment: I think so...I just wonder if I can skip the array method.It would be very helpful if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). In general, this allows you to define an Action that is executed when a KeyStroke is invoked. So you can have a different Action for each of the right/left/up/down arrow keys.

Comment: I am not allowed to use keyboard.:)